# SpringSecurity authentication not removing session from registry when closing browser

Tags: spring, grails, spring-security

Using grails 2.5+ and Spring 2.0

## EDIT

I see I was unclear. What I meant:  what is the configuration needed to clear these hanging sessions out of the spring registry- either after x amount of time or when the user logs in next time.

Right now it's a memory leak unless I manually sift through the registry and boot certain instances. Surely spring has a handler built in for this....

The docs have a property logout.invalidateHttpSession which is already set to true in my project.

---

Log out works fine. If I close the browser and reopen it, I have to log back in, which is desired.
HOWEVER, the previous session remains in the sessionRegistry.

The HttpSessionEventPublisher is registered in the web.xml

```
<listener>
     <listener-class>org.springframework.security.web.session.HttpSessionEventPublisher</listener-class>
</listener>
```

In resources.groovy I have

```
    sessionRegistry(SessionRegistryImpl)

    sessionAuthenticationStrategy(ConcurrentSessionControlStrategy, sessionRegistry) {
            maximumSessions = -1
    }

    concurrentSessionFilter(ConcurrentSessionFilter){
            sessionRegistry = sessionRegistry
            expiredUrl = '/login'
    }
```

Comment: well of course it won't be removed. You are basically yanking the power cord out-of-your-computer (the client) and you expect the server to notice that?

Comment: Closing a browser doesn't end a session. It abandons the session. The session is still active, but without a browser connected to it. This is the way HTTP works.

Comment: I clarified my question.

Comment: @M Deinum   Well, I would say I expect a fully featured session management plugin to have a convenient means of guessing that- as most game networking toolkits have